# selecting entire Razor date field without selecting individual month date and year

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, bootstrap-4, razor-pages

I have the following date field on my razor view:

```
  <label asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="control-label required" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
                        <input  asp-for="DateOfBirth" type="date"  class="form-control input-lg" required   />
                        <span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
                        
                    </div>
```

while entering the date, user has to select individual month date and year fields in order to type a new number, user does not want to select individual field. they just want to type month, date and year with out selecting individually so in the below screen shot, I need to select day first in order to enter new date and then month and then year, I cannot continuously type date, month and year.

[image]

[image]
[image]

is their any work around for this so that user can select the entire date field and type a new date without individually selecting date, month and year. This is how my Model looks like:

```
public partial class EmployeeInfo
{
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayName("Date")]
    public DateTime DateFormFilled { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

these are the packages installed in my project:

[image]
any help will be appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
<label asp-for="DateOfBirth" class="control-label required" style="font-weight:bold;"></label>
<input  asp-for="DateOfBirth" type="date"  class="form-control input-lg" required   />
<span asp-validation-for="DateOfBirth" class="text-danger"></span>
                        
                    </div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-a9jBBRygX1Bh5lt8GZjXDzyOB+bWve9EiO7tROUtj/E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: do you have any example

Comment: I added this in jsfiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx5b4nwq/) and I don't have to move the cursor to type.

Comment: sorry, I don't see the difference  between your code and my code. Yours is working of course without moving the cursor. what is the difference?

Comment: I put my Model too in my code. May be, something in the model. I created a new controller and date is behaving the same way, i have to individually select Month, day and year. could be related to razor syntax

Comment: No, I am not using calendar library. calendar pop up when I use type=date

Comment: I removed the `onkeydown` and changed it to be of type "date" and it works fine. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx5b4nwq/2/) It appears the browser will handle the formatting and not accept not numeric data as well as add the slashes.

Comment: The built-in browser date control works as you want it to. You shouldn't need to move the cursor from one segment of the date to another.

Comment: I removed the onkeydown and put type=date and still the same thing. I need to move the cursor from one segment to another

Comment: I posted all the packages installed in my project

Comment: @rimi added a code snippet to your post and it works fine.